# Calling "del" on result of Function call results in "SyntaxError: can't delete function call"

Tags: python, syntax-error, function-calls

Consider below example:

```
random_tile = random.choice(tiles)
del random_tile
```

It first assigns a random element from the list `tiles` to a variable, and then calls a function on that variable.

Then if we want to shorten the code as follows:

```
del random.choice(tiles)
```

We would get a `SyntaxError: can't delete function call`. I tried `eval()` with no luck. How can this be solved?

**EDIT:**

What I am trying to do is to remove a element from the `tiles` list *at random*. I thought I found a more compact way of doing it other than using `random.randint()` as the index, but I guess not.

Is there a pythonic/conventional way of doing this otherwise?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @pst updated title and question

Comment: @glibdud updated title and question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`del` is not a function, it is a keyword to create [del statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) e.g. `del var`. You can't use it as a function or on a function, it can only be applied to a variable name, list of variable names or subscriptions and slicings e.g.

```
del a
del a,b
del l[0]
del l[:]
```

**To remove the random item you can try this**

```
random_tile.remove(random.choice(tiles))
```

**BUT** it is not best way to remove items because it could mean a internal search for items and item comparison, also won't work if items are not unique, so best would be to get random index and delete that

```
index = random.randint(0, len(l)-1)
del l[index]
```

Comment: Also, its semantics mean it *does not make sense* to use on anything but a variable, attribute access, or collection lookup (`a[b]`).

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I used the last part in my answer.

Comment: @Osh see the edit depending on list size and what Title object is that may not be the best answer

Comment: In newer versions of Python, you can use `random.randrange()` to avoid that awkward `len(l) - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to actually modify your `tiles` list, your first attempt doesn't do it either. It just assigns to your variable, then wipes that variable. That's because `del` works on the variable itself, not what it points to. Most other functions work on the value some variable points to. So unless you actually need to use `del`, what you're trying to do will work fine.

Also, if you are trying to use `del`, i'm pretty sure you're using it wrong. If you elaborate more on what you're trying to do, we can probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to remove a random element from a list.  Here's one.

```
>>> import random
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_list.remove(random.choice(my_list))
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: this won't work in all cases e.g. when items are not unique + it means a search and comparison of items

Comment: I'm aware, I was reformatting the OP's code to fit his requirements.  I personally would use `my_list.pop(random.randint(0, len(my_list)-1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list `tiles` this does the trick:

```
import random
tiles.remove(random.choice(tiles))
```

Comment: This should work, but only if the values in `tiles` are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @Osh why are you trying to answer your own quesion when others have given the same answer, and as I said this is not the correct or best anwser in any case

Comment: @AnuragUniyal I actually posted my answer before any of the other answers (that addressed my actual problem), and before you updated your answer to fit my question. Thanks for your input though.