# Python error cannot delete function call

Tags: python-3.x

In python I tried calling a function in a function - when I finished it says "error cannot delete function call". Why is this happening? Inside the nested function there is a delete used, but that is for a different variable! I tried a few things like printing the function instead but got the same answer.

Here is the code which isn't working:

```
def BracketStart():
    Round2Normal=[] 
    Round1Loser=[]
    if len(List) % 2 == 0: 
        print("The Current Match Is %s VS %s" %(min(List),max(List)))
    starting=input("Start Match? --> ") 
    if starting=="Yes":
        Winner1=input("Who Won? --> ") 
        if Winner1==min(List): 
            Round2Normal.append(min(List)) 
            Round1Loser.append(max(List)) 
            del min(List)
            del max(List)
```

Comment: It might help if you showed the code of the function. Psychic debugging is beyond my abilities.

Comment: It is a very long line of code - but this is the line not working -  def BracketStart():
  Round2Normal=[]
  Round1Loser=[]
  if len(List) % 2 == 0:
    print("The Current Match Is %s VS %s" %(min(List),max(List)))
    starting=input("Start Match? --> ")
    if starting=="Yes":
     Winner1=input("Who Won? --> ")
     if Winner1==min(List):
      Round2Normal.append(min(List))
      Round1Loser.append(max(List))
      del min(List)
      del max(List)

Comment: when I try deleting a variable in the list at the end it says cannot delete function call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling "del" on result of Function call results in "SyntaxError: can't delete function call"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128856/calling-del-on-result-of-function-call-results-in-syntaxerror-cant-delete-f)

Comment: @RutvikMarathe It is a good practice to accept an answer, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`min(List)` *is* a function call -- so, yes, you are trying to delete a function call. Perhaps

```
List.remove(min(List))
```

is the sort of thing you want to do (though calling a list "List" isn't a good choice and removing elements from a list is a relatively expensive operation).